# Add item to a sql databse by pressing a button

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Im trying to add something to a list and at the same time add it to a database. This is done by pressing a button. This worked fine when I just add the item to the list, but when I added the database function, it stop working. The error starts at:

db.execSQL(createTable);

```
public class ItemDAO extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static final String DATABASENAME = "ItemsDB";
        private static final Integer DATABASEVERSION = 1;

        private static final String TABLEITEM = "Table";
        private static final String ITEM = "name";
        private static final String ID = "id";

        private Context context;

        public ItemDAO(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASENAME, null, DATABASEVERSION);
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLEITEM + "("
                    + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                    + ITEM + " TEXT" + " )";

            db.execSQL(createTable);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        }

        public void addItemToDatabase(Item item){

            ContentValues fila = new ContentValues();

            fila.put(ID, item.getId());
            fila.put(ITEM, item.getName());

            SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();

            database.insert(TABLEITEM, null, fila);

            database.close();
        }

        public List<Item> getItemsFromDatabases(){

            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLEITEM;

            SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();

            Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();

            while(cursor.moveToNext()){

                Item item = getItem(cursor);
                itemList.add(item);
            }

            cursor.close();
            database.close();
            return itemList;
        }


        private Item getItem(Cursor cursor){
            Item item = new Item();

            Integer itemID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ID));
            item.setId(itemID);

            String itemName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ITEM));
            item.setName(itemName);
            return item;
        }
    }
```

//Another class

```
public class ItemController {

    public void addItemToDB(Item item, Context context){
        ItemDAO itemDAO = new ItemDAO(context);
        itemDAO.addItemToDatabase(item);
    }

    public List<Item> getItemsFromDB(Context context){
        ItemDAO itemDAO = new ItemDAO(context);
        return itemDAO.getItemsFromDatabases();
    }

}
```

//Another class

```
public class FragmentMyList extends Fragment {
    private EditText editTxt;
    private Button btn;
    private ListView list;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View vistaADevolver = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_list, container, false);

        editTxt = (EditText)vistaADevolver.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        btn = (Button) vistaADevolver.findViewById(R.id.button);
        list = (ListView) vistaADevolver.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Adapter: You need three parameters 'the context, id of the layout (it will be where the data is shown),
        // and the array that contains the data
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList);

        // Here, you set the data in your ListView
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ItemController itemController = new ItemController();

                String itemName = editTxt.getText().toString();
                Item item = new Item();
                item.setName(itemName);
                item.setId(0);
                itemController.addItemToDB(item, getActivity());

                // this line adds the data of your EditText and puts in your array
                arrayList.add(itemName);
                // next thing you have to do is check if your adapter has changed
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return vistaADevolver;
    }
}
```

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.segunfamisa.sample.bottomnav, PID: 2792
                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Table": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Table(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT )
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1677)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1608)
                      at com.segunfamisa.sample.bottomnav.ItemDAO.onCreate(ItemDAO.java:45)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                      at com.segunfamisa.sample.bottomnav.ItemDAO.addItemToDatabase(ItemDAO.java:63)
                      at com.segunfamisa.sample.bottomnav.ItemController.addItemToDB(ItemController.java:15)
                      at com.segunfamisa.sample.bottomnav.FragmentMyList$1.onClick(FragmentMyList.java:52)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: I think it would help if you add error message...

Comment: There is the error

Comment: Do you already have a table called `Table` that you haven't cleared?

Comment: The only table I have is TABLEITEM

Comment: `Table` is a reserved word for most DBMS (ie, you can't use it). You will enclose the name within backticks to make this work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table is a reserved keyword in SQLLite, you cannot use it as a table name.
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Also watch out with the column name TEXT. This is not reserved in SQLLite, but in MySQL for example it is. Using this column name prevents you from making a switch to another database vendor in the future.

Comment: @MatiasNagore Nope! Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

Try some other name for table as it is a keyword and use \'table name here\' or \"table name here\"

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you have to put name of table which is **Table** into some kind of escape char (google says its " - double quote)

in ItemDAO:

```
 private static final String TABLEITEM = "\"Table\"";
```

Table is reserved keyword in SQLLite so usually it is **bad (*practice*) idea** to use reserved keywords as table and columns names. However if you have to you have to escape those names: [reference](http://blog.christosoft.de/2012/10/sqlite-escaping-table-acolumn-names/)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is working, I have not tested it, but it is possible. But please don't do this, using Table as a table name is a BAD practice.